# Can spin operator expectation value be time-independent while commutator with Hamiltonian is non-zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, commutator

Considering the following (magnetic field) hamiltonian: $\hat{H}=-\gamma B_z \hat{S}_z$ ($\gamma$ is a constant). Suppose an electron is in an eigenstate of $S_x$, and we ask ourselves the question whether the expected value of $S_z$ changes with time. This is not the case, as $[\hat{H}, \hat{S}_z]=0$.

Now suppose we are in an eigenstate of $S_z$, does the $S_x$ expectation value change with time? Logically I would say it does because of the answer to the previous question. However, $[\hat{H}, \hat{S}_x]\neq 0$ indicating time dependence. So, will the expectation value of $S_x$ change with time or not?

Comment: But... *look* at the m=1/2  eigenstate of $S_z$. It  gives  $\langle S_x\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The spin is undergoing [Larmor precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession) about the magnetic field, so yes the $x$ and $y$ components will change while the component parallel to the field remains fixed..

Comment: ...unless both x and y expectation values vanish.

Comment: Alright, so x and y components ofcourse change (i.e. are time dependent), but nevertheless the expectation values for x and y are constant ($=0$) (makes sense as the precession creates a perfect circle). I guess I should not be too quick to make assumptions solely on the Ehrenfest theorem.

Comment: @CosmosZachos. Only if $J=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "expectation of $x$ $y$" do you mean   $S_x$,  $S_y$?

Comment: Yes, consider J=1/2, and $\langle S_x\rangle=\langle S_y\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The Ehrenfest theorem uses the *expected value* of the commutator. i.e. for some operator $\hat{A}$ the Ehrenfest theorem says
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle\hat{A}\rangle = \frac{1}{i\hbar} \langle[\hat{A}, \hat{H}]\rangle + \langle\frac{\partial\hat{A}}{\partial t}\rangle.$$

In your case while $[\hat{S}_x, \hat{H}] \neq 0,$ its expectation value will still be zero thus the expectation value of $\hat{S}_x$ will not depend on time. Should be straightforward to show that $\langle[\hat{S}_x, \hat{S}_z]\rangle = 0$ with the spin commutator relations.

Edit: For your first point, if the only Hamiltonian is the one you've given then the particle won't be in an eigenstate of $\hat{S}_x$. If it was in such an eigenstate before the magnetic field was turned on the wavefunction will collapse into one of the possible $\hat{S}_z$ eigenstates once the field is turned on.